# Ruby on Rails application on docker ECS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm new to Ruby on Rails.

I have a rails 6 application that runs on docker container(with ECS Fargate)

I want to know if it's possible to set ruby on rails's environment settings from container Environment variable settings?
Basically, I don't want to commit my .env file to repo. and don't want to manage each environment settings from ruby on rails setting file. I would rather prefer to add it to task definition and fetch settings from it.

Can any one help?

Comment: Do you intend to do this via cli, sdk or the ECS GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you can use AWS Parameter Store to store environment or secrets
Check out this: https://medium.com/nordcloud-engineering/ssm-parameter-store-for-keeping-secrets-in-a-structured-way-53a25d48166a

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is great, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [Add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so that others will have some idea on what it is and why it’s here, then ***quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to*** in case the link becomes unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). See also [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass environment variables to your task when you launch them.

For example I have a simple ruby application that has:

```
configure :custom do
  set :redishost, ENV['REDIS_SERVER_ENDPOINT']
```

You can then refer to it as a variable in the code as `settings.redishost` .

When I launch this container as part of an ECS/Fargate task I include an environment variable called `REDIS_SERVER_ENDPOINT` which gets read by the Ruby program with the above code snippet. [This is the AWS doc that shows how to configure an environment variable in an ECS task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/taskdef-envfiles.html).

The problem with this is that if you are checking in the task definition into source control these variables will be visible in plain text.

Alternatively you could use AWS Secrets Manager to store the variables and refer to them (similarly) in the task definition. It requires a bit more wiring (which I have documented [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/securing-credentials-using-aws-secrets-manager-with-aws-fargate/)) but more secure.